# add an array to existing data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array like

```
array([[-8.76297433e-01],
       [-1.05157165e+00],
       [ 9.97287956e-02],
       [ 9.97287956e-02],
       [-1.22684587e+00],
       [-1.22684587e+00],
       [-1.22684587e+00],
       [-8.76297433e-01]])
```

i want to add this as a column to my existing data frame of same number of rows as that of array.

Comment: And where ist your code that exactly tries that? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: try `df['new_col'] = arr`, where `arr` is your array.

Comment: Thanks. I used to convert that to array using np.array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# your array
a = np.array([[-8.76297433e-01],
              [-1.05157165e+00],
              [ 9.97287956e-02],
              [ 9.97287956e-02],
              [-1.22684587e+00],
              [-1.22684587e+00],
              [-1.22684587e+00],
              [-8.76297433e-01]])

# your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['col1'])
df

# add columns
df['col2'] = a

# show the result
df
```